# Overflow-detecting conversion from String to Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

The `read` function is useful for converting `String` to `Int`, but it does not support error handling. Especially, it silently returns an incorrect value when the string value is too large to be represented as `Int`:

```
> read "123456789012345678901234567890" :: Int
-4362896299872285998
```

How can I check if the string value is between `minBound :: Int` and `maxBound :: Int` and thus correctly converted to `Int`? Is there an overflow-detecting conversion function that returns `Maybe Int` or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert it first to `Integer`, and perform the comparison:

```
> (read "123456789012345678901234567890" :: Integer) > toInteger(maxBound::Int)
True
```